# MongoDB Record To Array Takes Forever

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, heroku, mongohq

I'm getting information from the database (MongoDB) and then converting it to an array like that:

```
 @bs = coll.find("headers.from" => { "$regex" => email, "$options" => 'i' }, "date" => {"$gte" => initial_date, "$lte" => Time.now.utc})
      puts "a seguir ao fetch"


      puts @bs

      @bs = @bs.to_a
```

This works very well but sometimes, it just enters in an infinite cycle (I believe) because It crashes my heroku app.

The response (the first line is the print of @bs):

```
2011-05-14T17:05:46+00:00 app[web.1]: DBResponse(flags=, cursor_id=, start=)

2011-05-14T17:06:16+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET yapi.heroku.com/api/v1/69399ead0ed4ded38e7a101f7c8faf/2011-2-1.json dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-05-14T17:06:47+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET yapi.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-05-14T17:07:10+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET yapi.heroku.com/api/v1/69399ead0ed4ded38e7a101f7c8faf/2011-2-1.json dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-05-14T17:07:17+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET yapi.heroku.com/api/v1/69399ead0ed4ded38e7a101f7c8faf/2011-2-1.json dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-05-14T17:07:51+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET yapi.heroku.com/api/v1/69399ead0ed4ded38e7a101f7c8faf/2011-2-1.json dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
```

I'd like to know why because I really can't find out why with all the debug information. IT just holds on the ".to_a" forever and the server is blocked.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, there is no reason for RoR to terminate this loop.

If you can, try initializing it as a Kernel#Array. Try this:

```
Array([1,2,3]) #=> [1, 2, 3]
Array(123) #=> [123]
```

Instead of:

```
arg = arg.to_a
```

Comment: What do you mean defined as? sorry, dont understand

Comment: I imagine that is a RoR method? Converting to array?

Comment: Yes, I know. Where is it coming from and why is it necessary? Consider using Kernel#Array instead.

Comment: I believe I have to make a .to_a the result that comes from MongoDB? IS there any other way of doing it? Can you edit your answer please? Thanks